# Missing month and day in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have Date values, few dates are complete (format: yyyy-mm-dd but as text, not in date format), but few dates are having missing month and missing day value,
for which now I will have to add the missing month and day. Example: if day is missing, first of that month has to be added to the date and if month and day are missing 1st of jan has to be added to the year part, In sql I was able to concatenate simply with the number as following:

```
CASE  WHEN LENGTH(<t>1.CMSTDT) = 4  THEN TO_DATE(<t>1.CMSTDT ||'-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')  
WHEN LENgTH(<t>1.CMSTDT) = 7  THEN TO_DATE(<t>1.CMSTDT ||'-01','YYYY-MM-DD')  
ELSE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(<t>1.CMSTDTC\,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD') END
```

Now Similar concatenation must be done in POSTGRESQL and I tried using CAST and to_char and few other functions, but I was unable to concatenate the values, can anyone help me on this.I am very new to POSTGRESQL, I am not aware which function to use in this case.

Yes, that 1.CMSTDT is a date part which is used in SQL not in POSTgresql, My results has to look like this:

```
Actual Values   Results 
2014-06         2014-06-01
1998-08         1998-08-01
1986            1986-01-01
```

Comment: What is your current result, and what query you try? `<t>1.CMSTDT` doesnt seem ok for postgres. Postgres function string are [**HERE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: What type is `ActualValues`?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Yes, but you didnt say what type is `Actual Values` or `Result` can be string or dates

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion, the actual values are in text, and i need to concatenate and convert to date format

Comment: Did you get any error or something? Because I just realize my query is almost the same as your, but I use `char_length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d914/3)**

I create the table with the expected result to see if match after the `CASE`

```
SELECT 
       "Values",
       "Results",
       CASE WHEN char_length("Values") > 8 THEN TO_DATE("Values", 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            WHEN char_length("Values") > 5 THEN TO_DATE("Values" || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            ELSE TO_DATE("Values" || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
       END as "Result1"
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|     Values |                   Results |                   Result1 |
|------------|---------------------------|---------------------------|
| 2014-06-01 |    June, 01 2014 00:00:00 |    June, 01 2014 00:00:00 |
|    1998-08 |  August, 01 1998 00:00:00 |  August, 01 1998 00:00:00 |
|       1986 | January, 01 1986 00:00:00 | January, 01 1986 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: remember accept the answer if solve your problem and upvote when have privileges